# Increment a value of column in pandas/csv file when the row is appended in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, concatenation

I have this code which selects a column from a csv file and appends it as a row to another csv file:

```
def append_pandas(s,d):
    import pandas as pd
    df = pd.read_csv(s, sep=';', header=None)
    df_t = df.T
    df_t.iloc[0:1, 0:1] = 'Time Point'
    df_t.columns = df_t.iloc[0]
    df_new = df_t.drop(0)
    pdb = pd.read_csv(d, sep=';')
    newpd = pdb.append(df_new)
    from pandas import DataFrame
    newpd.to_csv(d, sep=';')
```

As you can see, there is a Time Point column, and every time the row is appended, I want the value in this column to increment by 1. For example, when the first row is appended, it is 0, the second row will have 1, the third row will have 3 etc.

Could you please help with this?

The resulting file looks like this:

```
Time Point     A   B   C ...
         1    23  65  98  
         2    10  24  85
         3     1  54  72
         4    33  77   0 
         5     7  73  81
         6   122  43   5 # <- row added with new Time Point
```

P.S. The Row which is being appended doesn't have a Time Point value and looks like this:

```
   Well ID   Cell Count
         A          100
         B          200 
         C           54
         D           77
         E           73
         F           49
```

The resulting file shouldn't have the headers of the first file added either ('Well ID','Cell Count'); so just the values of the 'Cell Count' column.

Please, help :(

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: I don't know how to increment value of 'Time Point' by one when the row is added to the document..

Comment: Please provide your data as **text**

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean? Should I just print it?

Comment: Hi, I just added both as text!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following code and check the output CSV file:

```py
import io
import pandas as pd

# Load an empty CSV file and read it as dataframe
empty_csv = 'Time Point;A;B;C;D;E;F'
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(empty_csv), sep=';')

# Load a CSV file which will be added to `df` defined above
add_csv = 'Well ID;Cell Count\nA;100\nB;200\nC;54\nD;77\nE;73\nF;49\n'
df_add = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(add_csv), sep=';')

def append_a_row(df, df_add):
    df_add = df_add.set_index('Well ID').T
    df_add.insert(0, 'Time Point', len(df)+1)
    return df.append(df_add)

df_new = append_a_row(df, df_add)

# Save as csv
d = 'path_to_the_output.csv'
df_new.to_csv(d, sep=';', index=False)
```

Comment: Heyy, I have tried it but it gives me this: KeyError: "None of ['Time Point'] are in the columns"

Comment: Provide your data as text, not a screenshot.

Comment: Sorry, I have just added it. I hope it helps..

Comment: Thanks. In your initial post, the first column name was `ID` not `Well ID`. That's why you got an error. Please write your information precisely, otherwise how can we provide right solutions?

Comment: I'll edit my answer soon. Wait a second.

Comment: @mariant, check my updated answer please.

Comment: Is it appending the row to previously existing file though?

Comment: Ah, it's my bad. I misunderstood you wanted to just transfom the existing csv. I'll modify that.

Comment: Sorry, I might have not be clear enough.. Essentially, I have an empty csv file just with headers: 'Time Point', 'A', 'B', 'C'.. etc. And I want the new row to be added with incremented Time Point value, and saved :) The following rows will be appended to this file creating one big csv.

Comment: @mariant, check my updated answer please.

Comment: Oooomg, it worked finally!! Thank you so so so muuuuch <3

Comment: Cool. Good luck with your project:)